# No parallelism in Express Edition of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, parallelism, windows-server-2019

I have SQL Server 2019 Express Edition (CU8) on Windows Server 2019 (1809 version) and all of my queries go serial with `NoParallelPlansInDesktopOrExpressEdition` in `NoparallelPlanReason` property.

Is it that Express Edition never goes parallel? I cannot find anything about this in Microsoft documentation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: @Ronaldo Windows Server 2019 (1809 version)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The limitation is mentioned in the [Query Processing Architecture Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#parallel-query-processing) under the "Parallel Query Processing" section:

> Parallel plans not supported for Desktop and Express edition.

The [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2019 (15.x)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#Cross-BoxScaleLimits) documentation says (under "Scale Limits") that Express is:

> Limited to lesser of 1 socket or 4 cores

But that is just related to how many cores you can make available to the database engine.
It doesn't say anything about parallel plans (other than a limitation related to batch mode operations being limited to 1 core on Express Edition).

All that to say that it looks like Express really doesn't allow parallel plans at all.  I tried running queries on SQL Server 2019 and 2014 with the same NonParallelPlanReason given, so it doesn't appear to be a new limitation either.

Comment: Great and complete answer Josh. Many thanks. Hopefully this will spread the fact across the world :-)